# Image is not in center on safari mobile web

Tags: css, animation, mobile, safari, css-animations

I implemented css animation to the image and it works well on explorer or chrome through the pc.

Though, on safari, the image is placed in the left top corner. Since I'm using position: absolute and relative for animation, I can't use display:flex option.

Plus, as you can see from below ss, card size is also not fit as applied in css, and have weird space between card and buttons.

[current status on safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UyHi.jpg)

Here is my current code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("../../images/background-forloading.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flip-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  perspective: 1600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(40px) rotateX(-8deg) rotateY(10deg);
  animation: movement 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes movement {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-40px) rotateX(8deg) rotateY(-10deg);
  }
}

.flip-card div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.7s;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;

}

.flip-card div img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}


.front {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px #000);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.flip-card:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-card:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px rgb(120, 185, 232));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="images/귀문관카드뒤.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="images/인간.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-button text-center">
    <a href="images/인간.png" download="인간.png"><button class="enter">Save</button></a>
    <a href="final.html"><button type="submit" class="enter">Next</button></a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it solves your problem, but your code is currently missing the browser prefixes.

- `-webkit-` for Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS
- `-moz-` Firefox
- `-ms-` Internet Explorer and Edge